# Is there a way to inherit Schema of custom schematic?

Tags: command-line-interface, angular-schematics

Using Angular Schematics, I would like to build a schematic which inherits the schema from a "Base" schematic (which is private and hidden, so it cannot be executed from CLI).

So when I run:

```
schematics @my-schematic:foo
```

I would like "foo" schematic to have the base schema and its own schema merged.
I would also like foo to inherit Rules from the base.

My understanding is that this would require some custom dev (like turning my-schematic into a class which would inherit from a base class etc). However, what I would like to know is whether there is a better, built-in way to do this? Like can schematic A extend schematic B in some way?

The collection.json schema has an "extends" field, but it seems to me it's more like a override.